# A simple question on showing the limit of a matrix is zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $$A_n = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0.25 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & \vdots\\
0 & 0.25 & 0 & 1 & \dots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0.25 & 0 & \dots& \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 1\\
0 & \dots & \dots & \dots & 0.25 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ Where $A_n$ is a $n$ by $n$ matrices.
How to show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} A_n^{k} = 0$ for all $n$ ?
I tried to estimate the spectral radius $\rho(A_n)$ and show that $\rho(A_n) < 1$.
But it fails, it there are better way to do this?

Comment: From the text, it seems that all matrices $A_n$ are the same and not zero. Can you elaborate on what do you mean?

Comment: I have slightly modified the question.

Comment: I feel like $A_n^2 = 1/4 I_n$

Comment: Not true, my bad. Although the computation of $A_n^2$ seems to be interesting for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,2^2,\ldots,2^{n-1})$. Then $DA_nD^{-1}$ is a symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix whose super-diagonal and sub-diagonal entries are $\frac12$ and whose main diagonal entries are zero. It follows that $\pm I+DA_nD^{-1}$ is an irreducible diagonally dominant matrix such that strict diagonal dominance occurs on row 1. Therefore $\pm I+DA_nD^{-1}$ is nonsingular, i.e. the eigenvalues of $A_n$ are not $\pm1$. However, by Gerschgorin disc theorem, all eigenvalues of $A_n$ lie on the **closed** unit disc. Since $A_n$ also has a real spectrum (because it is similar to the symmetric matrix $DA_nD^{-1}$), its eigenvalues must lie inside the **open** unit disc, meaning that $\rho(A_n)<1$.